# Nativescript IOS app crashes with fatal Javascript error

Tags: ios, angular2-nativescript

We have built a Nativescript angular app which runs fine on android, but when we run it on IOS it crashes with the following error:

> Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
>   Native stack trace: 2017-08-30 14:53:14.121870+0200
>   vendingappui[875:379513] 1 0x1006b2124 -[TNSRuntime
>   executeModule:referredBy:] 1 0x1006b2124 -[TNSRuntime
>   executeModule:referredBy:] 2017-08-30 14:53:14.123362+0200
>   vendingappui[875:379513] 2 0x1000c0054 main 2 0x1000c0054 main
>   2017-08-30 14:53:14.123456+0200 vendingappui[875:379513] 3 0x18f81d59c
>   3 0x18f81d59c  JavaScript stack trace: 1
>   @file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/view-util.js:7:35
>   JavaScript error: 2017-08-30 14:53:14.124343+0200
>   vendingappui[875:379513]
>   file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/view-util.js:7:35: JS
>   ERROR Error: Could not find module ‘ui/builder/special-properties’.
>   Computed path
>   ‘/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69ED44E3-BF9C-4CD4-81B5-5DB0E45AC583/vendingappui.app/app/tns_modules/ui/builder/special-properties’.
>
> file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/view-util.js:7:35: JS
>   ERROR Error: Could not find module ‘ui/builder/special-properties’.
>   Computed path
>   ‘/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69ED44E3-BF9C-4CD4-81B5-5DB0E45AC583/vendingappui.app/app/tns_modules/ui/builder/special-properties’.

The app is using Telerik Backend Services for Push Notifications and User Management.
Tns version 3.1.2.
tns-ios verson: 3.1.1

Please any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does these plugins supported by both iOS and Android? Try uninstalling them and run ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it b y deleting and reinstalling the tns-core modules. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The automatic install of peer dependencies was explicitly removed with npm 3
You need to manually install some of the peer dependencies and, you must check if there are the same versions.
I tried these steps:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
sudo npm i @angular/core@<version>
sudo npm i @angular/compiler@<version>
sudo npm i @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@<version>
```

...

After each peer dependency is installed, you will see if there's a version mismatch or if there's some other component that is missing. Hope I helped.